Definition of diferentiability in 2 variables
In my college they gave this definition for differentiablitity in two variables: A function $f:U\to \mathbb R$ is differentiable at a point $(x_0,y_0)$ if the increment $$ \Delta f( x_0,y_0)(h)= f((x_0,y_0)+h)-f(x_0,y_0)$$ verifies $$ \Delta f( x_0,y_0)(h)= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)h_x+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)h_y+\varepsilon _{x}(h)h_x+\varepsilon _{y}(h)h_y$$ where the $\varepsilon$'s tend to $0$ as $h$ tends to $0$. My question is how does this relate to the following usual definition (which is found a textbook recommended by the proffesor: Marsden, 6th edition): $f$ is differentiable if $$ \frac{f((x_0,y_0)+h)-f(x_0,y_0)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)h_x-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)h_y}{\left\|h \right\|}$$ tends to $0$ as $h\to 0$.

if the $ \epsilon$ tend to 0 it's the same.

If you prove that the second definition implies the first I give you an upvote

To the best of my knowledge, $f((x_0,y_0)+h)$ does not have a universal definition.
$(x_0,y_0)$ is a point and $h$ is a scalar so they can not be added directly.  Does your textbook use different definitions?  is this $h$ two dimensional?
Note: your 2nd and 3rd lines distinguish $h_x$ and $h_y$ so partially avoid this difficulty.

$h=(h_x,h_y)$ that's it

The definitions are equivalent.
For the proof from the first definition to the second, it suffices to show that
$$\frac{\varepsilon_x(h) h_x + \varepsilon_y(h) h_y}{\| h \|} \to 0 \qquad \text{as} \qquad h \to 0.$$
This follows immediately from the squeeze theorem: since
$$\frac{|h_x|}{\| h \|} \leqslant 1 \qquad \text{and} \qquad \frac{|h_y|}{\| h \|} \leqslant 1,$$
it follows that
$$\begin{align*} \left| \frac{\varepsilon_x(h) h_x + \varepsilon_y(h) h_y}{\| h \|} \right| & \leqslant |\varepsilon_x(h)| \cdot \frac{|h_x|}{\| h \|} + |\varepsilon_y(h)| \cdot \frac{|h_y|}{\| h \|} \\[1ex]
& \leqslant |\varepsilon_x(h)| + |\varepsilon_y(h)| \to 0.
\end{align*}$$
For the other direction, it suffices to show that if a function $\varepsilon : B(0, r) \setminus \{ 0 \} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\varepsilon(h)}{\| h \|} = 0,$$
then $\varepsilon(h) = \varepsilon_x(h) \cdot h_x + \varepsilon_y(h) \cdot h_y$ for some functions $\varepsilon_x, \varepsilon_y : B(0, r) \setminus \{ 0 \} \to \mathbb{R}$ that tend to $0$ as $h \to 0$. Indeed, let
$$\begin{align*}
\varepsilon_x(h) & = \frac{\varepsilon(h)}{|h_x| + |h_y|} \operatorname{sgn}(h_x), \\[1ex]
\varepsilon_y(h) & = \frac{\varepsilon(h)}{|h_x| + |h_y|} \operatorname{sgn}(h_y).
\end{align*}$$
Then clearly $\varepsilon(h) = \varepsilon_x(h) \cdot h_x + \varepsilon_y(h) \cdot h_y$. Moreover, since $\| h \| \leqslant |h_x| + |h_y|$, we have that
$$\left| \varepsilon_x(h) \right| \leqslant \left| \frac{\varepsilon(h)}{\| h \|} \right| \qquad \text{and} \qquad \left| \varepsilon_y(h) \right| \leqslant \left| \frac{\varepsilon(h)}{\| h \|} \right|,$$
hence both tend to $0$ as $h \to 0$.

Oh wait, it's the wrong direction. Gimme a second...

Isn't definition 1 only a sufficient condition for definition 2?

@ManuelOcaña They are equivalent, see the updated answer.
